# using a looop to add user input to the set and dict in order discovered

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to write a small program that does a few things. First is:

Write a while loop that repeatedly creates a list of words from a line of input from the user. So I did this:

```
s = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
while True: 
    pos = 0
    for c in s: 
        if c == " ":
            print(s[:pos])
            s = s [pos+1:]
            break
        pos += 1
    else:
        print(s)
        break
```

I need to add the user inputted words to the set and dict and then display their value in the order in which the program discovered them. I believe I need another loop but I'm not sure. I'm pretty lost at this point and the above is as far as I can seem to come on this program. Any help is appreciated as I am (obviously)new at python.

Comment: Your objective is not clear. Can you restate more precisely what you need to achieve? What do you mean by 'the set and dict'? Do you mean '*a* set *or* *a* dict'? What do you mean by 'their value in the order...'? Do 'their' refer to the words? If you need to display the words in the order they appear in the input, why not just print what the user entered?

Comment: Sure sorry it's unclear @hugowood. I need to: Write a while loop that repeatedly creates a list of words from a line of input from the user.
Loop through the list of words and add each one to the set. If the set increases in size (indicating this word has not been processed before), add the word to the dict as a key with the value being the new length of the set.
Using another loop, display the list of words in the dict along with their value, which represents the order in which they were discovered by the program.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow that's a pretty detailed specification; what exactly is the problem you're having? You haven't yet included either a dictionary or a set, perhaps you should start by finding out how to do that.

Comment: So I wrote the above program to write a loop that creates a list of words from the user input. I'm trying to do the next step. Create a list of words to add to the set and if it increases  add it to the dict but I'm lost as to how to do that @jonrsharpe  edit: I read up on dict {} and   set () I'm unsure how to incorporate that into the code. I'll read more I just tend to do better with examples.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow that's not what your current code does. I think you need to work out how to actually create a list and add the words to it, rather than just showing them. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: thanks for the link, as I said I'm really new and this self teaching is not going quite how I planned. Any shove in the right direction is helpful thank you!@jonrsharpe

Comment: FWIW I learned from Mark Lutz's Learning Python: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do